# joomla file upload module assign to menu

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Module Name: Simple File Upload v1.3

Module Source: [File Upload Module](http://wasen.net/index.php/projects/simple-file-upload)

Just today i got very clear clarity on this questions.

My questions is, With module we can set the positions only, we could not able to assign to menu directly in admin menus. but can call the module in article. but actual requirement is. i want to show the upload form in the admin area. so i want to create one menu in the admin menus, when user click this menu. appropriate upload form will be display.

How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To assign module to a menu,Go to extensions -> module manager, Then open your module `Simple File Upload v1.3` and On the bottom left you will find **Menu Assignment** section select the menu there where you want to assign that module.

[image]

And hit save.

**OR**

You can also do this by menu manager also go menu manager under which menus where you want to assign that module Go to edit view and on the right under **Module Assignment for this Menu Item** click on the module name then popup will open and follow the instruction as described above.And save you are done .

Read more : [How do you assign a module to specific pages?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_module_to_specific_pages%3F)

Hope this will help.